# c++ read stdin from heredoc

Tags: c++, stream, std

If I have my command line such as:

```
foo arg1 arg2 << HEREDOC
  line1
  line2
HEREDOC
```

In foo, how can i get value from heredoc?

```
int main( char *argv[] )
{
  string arg1=argv[1];
  string arg2=argv[2];

  string heredoc= ?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heredoc just redirects stuff into `stdin`. So you can use:

```
string str;
while (getline(cin, str))
    cout << str << endl;
```

Comment: I'm getting `Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid`

Comment: @francoisrv This is probably because your main is incorrectly declared. It needs to be `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. (There are other correct declarations though)

Comment: yes it works now `#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
 string db = argv[1];
 
 string str;
 
 string query;

 while (getline(cin, str))
  query=query + str;
  
  cout << query;
  
  return 1;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Here document is yet another way to do IO redirection.
Your shell command is basically puts lines `line1` and then `line2` into `stdin` of your program.

So your code should look like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
// notice that your main declaration isn't conforming to C++ standard.
// it need additional argc parameter
{
  string arg1=argv[1];
  string arg2=argv[2];

  string heredoc_string1, heredoc_string2;
  getline(cin, heredoc_string1); 
  getline(cin, heredoc_string2);
}
```